# Tensorflow-Keras how to get reproducible results across different machines

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reproducible-research

I am trying to get exact reproducibility when running the training of a very simple model with tf-keras over different machines. For instance I have mahcine A, and B, and I would like the weights I get when calling `model.fit()` to be exactly identical on A and B. The code executes on CPU on both machines.

The two machines are running the same version of Python 3.8.10, and the same exact virtualenv.

I have already set the rng seeds for python random, numpy, and tensorflow:

```py
random.seed(seed)
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

I am also setting the following environment variables in the code:

```
import os 
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```

In addition to this, I am further running the code with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` to make sure everything is strictly on CPU (one of the machines has a GPU).

With all these settings, I am able to get the weights to be exactly identical during the model intiializtion, however, wehenever I can the `fit()` function, on exactly the same data, the weights start to diverge across the two machines.

Does anyone know how to get reproducible training across machines with TF-Keras?

Comment: Hi! You can use enable_op_determinism at the beginning of code to get deterministic results. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism